# accessing and displaying arrays of objects via api with react.ts

Tags: typescript, api, react-tsx

i am trying to display list of steps/ingredients from the recipe api with react.ts but i am unsure how to define the type of nested array of objects.

i am able to access the title, image and summary but not the steps in analizedInstructions.

```
export function RecipeDetails() {
    const initialRecipeState = {
        title: '',
        analizedInstructions: [{
            steps: [{
                name: ''
            }]
        }],
        image: '',
        summary: ''
        
    }

    const { id } = useParams();
    const [data, setData] = useState<RecipeData>(initialRecipeState);

    useEffect( () => {
        const getData = async() => {
            const newData = await fetchData(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/information?apiKey=key&includeNutrition=false`)
            setData(newData)
        }
        getData();
        console.log(data.analizedInstructions)
    },[])
```

this is my types file

```
export type RecipeData = {
    title: string,
    analizedInstructions: Steps,
    image: string,
    summary: string
}

export type Steps = {
    name: Name
}
export type Name = {
    name: string
}
```

and this is the data i get from the api im tying to access
[api data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjMGn.png)

i tried to find a solution via stackoverflow but didnt find quite what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export type RecipeData = {
    title: string,
    analizedInstructions: Instruction[],
    image: string,
    summary: string
}

export type Instruction = {
   steps: Step[]
}

export type Step = {
    name: string
}
```